# Is there any way that I can access executable through python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, executable

I am currently working on calling external executable file through python and perform some action on executable files.

I am able to open executable file through below command.

```
import os
path = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\abc.exe'
os.startfile(path)
```

below is the screen shot of the application that opens.

[image]

Is it possible to perform below task through python script
1) Click on Browse Button.
2) Give appropriate file path for the firmware
3) Click on Flash Firmware

**Note : The Application is 3rd party application.

Comment: note `path = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\abc.exe'` doesn't work, you need raw prefix :)

Comment: ok. then consider it is as path - r'C:Users\Me\Documents\abc.exe